# How I can navigate page a page clicking next button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to navigate into a web with a lof of pages, and I try to click next button to pass to the next page. The web is: https://www.truity.com/search-careers
My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

path = 'C:/Users/.../chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.truity.com/search-careers")

while True:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody//a')

    links = []
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        links.append(elements[i].get_attribute('href'))

    for link in links:
        print('navigating to: ' + link)
        driver.get(link)
        # Title
        title.append(driver.title)
        #....

        driver.back()
        
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div[4]/ul/li[11]/a').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

But my code is not correct. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: "But my code is not correct." is too generic. Can you specify what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[4]/ul/li[11]/a").click()
```

Alternative:

```
for i in range(1000):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[@title='Go to page {i+1}']").click()
    except:
        print('No more pages')
        break
```

Comment: My error: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @SoniaAparicio try if the alternatives i gave you works

Comment: Yes but this code go to the page 1 iteratively. I need to click the next button but I don't get it :(

Comment: @SoniaAparicio with the first line of code you are actually clicking the next button, with the second alternative you are ciclying on all the possible pages for "i" in the range that you want

Comment: Yes, I know but the code to click next button not work to me. And the second alternative going to page 1 iteratively. The problem with go page to page its that only is visible the number 1 to number 9, and there are 17 pages for what  I need click next and not the button number+1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.find_element_by_link_text()`

```
page_num = 1

while True:

    #insert the code to scrape this page
    #.....
    #.....

    print(f'On page {page_num}')
    
    
    #moving to next page
    page_num+=1
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num)).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('End of pages')
        break
    time.sleep(3)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: The problem with this code its that the last page is number 9 while there are 17 pages. I try to click by  link text the 'next >' button but its no correct ... :(

Comment: That is because the text inside the next button is `next ›` and not `next >`. The arrow symbol is different and therefore the code does not work properly.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter how many pages are visible below, if you run the code block I gave it will go to all the 17 pages and then end. I've added the output image to make it clear. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: In my computer, stop in page 9: On page 9
End of pages

Answer (score 0):

To simply loop through all the links and the 17 pages. Wait for all a href elements to be there and grab their href value. Add a time.sleep() incase of stale element error and also wait for the next tag to be clickable. Driver.back() would be an extra step since you just need all the href values and driver.get() to them.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get("https://www.truity.com/search-careers")
title=[]
links=[]
while True:
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='block-system-main']/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody//a")))
    for elem in elements:
        links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.next > a"))).click()
    except (NoSuchElementException,TimeoutException) as e:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    
for link in links:
    print('navigating to: ' + link)
    driver.get(link)
    # Title
    title.append(driver.title)
    #....
```

Imports

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
```